# Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba

Users have an Excel spreadsheet. To save it, they press a button which runs the below VBA code.

The code attempts to save the Excel spreadsheet to a network location amending the file name with today's date.

Intermittently the code will fail with

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed".

The script is:

```
Public Sub Copy_Save_R2()
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim fDate As Date

    fDate = Worksheets("Update").Range("D3").Value

    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

    With wbNew
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Q:\R2 Portfolio Prints\#Archive - R2 Portfolio\" & "R2 Portfolio - CEC A " & Format(fDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    End With

    Sheets("Update").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically; your code cannot access the mapped drive

Answer (score 3):

As Hugo stated, it could be an issue with the mapped drive. I prefer to use the full UNC path (\\Thismachine\...), in case the workbook gets used on a machine that doesn't have the mapped drive set up.

I thought the missing extension could be the problem, but I just tested it in Excel 2013 and it automatically added .xlsx to the filename.

<strike>The issue is probably due to the `wbNew` reference. It's completely unnecessary and should not be combined with `ActiveWorkbook`</strike>. Basically, you should have either a reference to a workbook, or use the predefined `ActiveWorkbook` reference. I'd also recommend using `ThisWorkbook` instead, since the user might click on another book while code is running.

```
Public Sub Copy_Save_R2()
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim fDate As Date

    fDate = Worksheets("Update").Range("D3").Value

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Q:\R2 Portfolio Prints\#Archive - R2 Portfolio\R2 Portfolio - CEC A " & Format(fDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Update").Activate
End Sub
```

Edit: Added `Application.DisplayAlerts` commands to prevent any Save popups, such as using .xlsx instead of .xlsm, and overwriting an existing copy.

Edit 2018-08-11: Added escape backslashes to fix UNC path display. Added strike-through to inaccurate statement about the `With` statement (see comments below). Basically, since nothing between `With` and `End With` begins with a `.`, the statement isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: The `wbNew` would not cause any issues, it's just completely redundant and unused., it doesn't affect any other lines of code though.

Comment: You are correct, `wbNew` wouldn't cause any problems by itself, and I should have been more clear in my explanation. In the original code sample, a `with` statement is used in addition to ActiveWorkbook, which basically results in `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs...`

Comment: @EricHarlan Just came across this because someone suggested this as a duplicate for a new question.  FWIW the `With` block in the original code wouldn't affect things - only if it said `.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` (i.e. with a leading `.`) would it be treated as `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`.  The `With` block in the original code wasn't actually being made use of, and therefore could be removed, but wouldn't have caused any errors.

Comment: Good point, @YowE3K and Wolfie (can only tag one user). I've updated my answer. Sorry I didn't follow when it was originally pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the cause of this error, and then remembered I was working on a version of my spreadsheet that had been recovered. Once I manually saved the recovered file and reopened it there was no problem with the vba code to save the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message when saving a workbook with a dynamic file name to a network location. Saving stage suddenly stopped working. Error 1004 Workbook SaveAs method failed.

Realised after a while that the location where the macro saved the output had changed and the macro's script had been tweaked by the team to reflect the new network address.

Whilst the new network address was accurate, it was simply too long...
I shortened the folder names, as well as the file name and bingo... Workbooks are being saved again, with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

When it happened to me, I added a command before the save.

```vb
On Error Resume Next
    Kill TargetFullname
On Error GoTo 0

wb.SaveCopyAs TargetFullname
```

(I also use `application.display=false`)

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly, my issue with `SaveAs` is how you supply the parameter

```
resultWb.SaveAs storageFolder & filePrefix & curYear & ".xlsx"
'This create error 1004

fullFilePath = storageFolder & filePrefix & curYear & ".xlsx"
resultWb.SaveAs fullFilePath
'No error
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Ensure your workbook is not shared. I guess "Shared" workbooks have limitations.

Saw this here:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/27843-save-xls-as-txt

In the "Review" tab click "Share Workbook" and ensure "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This allows workbook merging" is **unchecked**.