# Run time error '1004': SaveAs object _workbook failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to run the code successfully on most of the laptops, only few laptops are giving this error.

I am trying to copy the sheet from current excel to another excel and save it on a shared folder location.

I have tried changing Activeworkbook.saveas  to thisworkbook saveas to be more specific and not confuse excel

I am still not able to solve this issue and am not able to find any solutions online.

The code is given below(only relevant part which is causing error). It runs perfectly fine without any error on some laptops. Only 3-4 laptops out of 20 are giving this error.

Ok i found out one thing. If i am saving it on local folder it is ok. But when the link is to the server folder on the intranet, it is giving error. Any idea how to resolve?

```
Sub saveme()
 Dim name as Variant
 Set thiswb = ActiveWorkbook
 chk = thiswb.Path
 name= Range("E4").Value


'directory of shared folder
chng = "C:\Ananth\MBL\Excel\MBL EPM\Final1\Shared MBL"

' some lines of code


 'send file into the shared folder

   Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").name = "new"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=newbook.Worksheets(1)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  newbook.Worksheets("new").Delete

   ChDir chng

   newbook.SaveAs Filename:=chng & "\" & name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:=name, writeResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=False

 ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest setting the ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook to a variable so that you can easily check it with code. Also, it would be good to check that the path exists by using string = dir(path) to check for the presence of a file at that path.  You might check this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138908/run-time-error-1004-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed

Comment: i have set variable for the both the current workbook and the new one which i opened.

Comment: Code is difficult to follow and parts seem to be missing. Why are there two almost identical paths `loc` and `chng` ? Where is `name` declared and populated?  Where is `Line3` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'\_Workbook' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138908/run-time-error-1004-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed)

Comment: Hello, sorry for the missing code, i have removed parts which are irrelevant and put only the part which is giving an error. I am not able to understand why the code runs well in some and gives error in the others. I am declaring the existing and new workbooks in variables

Comment: Shouldn't `chn & name` be `chng & "\" & name` - i.e. fix the typo and include a path separator?

Comment: Sorry edited that. it is not the issue. It was a typo here while posting question.

Comment: tried the changes as mentioned in this link. Still the error comes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138908/run-time-error-1004-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed

Comment: Have you checked that the users have the relevant directory on their C: drive?  (I'm surprised that the comment says that something on the C: drive is "shared")

Comment: The drive is actually a shared folder present on the server. Each user (employee) has access to the drive. i am able to open the shared folder. So there is access for employees.

Comment: Ok i found out one thing. If i am saving it on local folder it is ok. But when the link is to the server folder it is giving error. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Have you checked that the users have access to the relevant shared directory?  (It's a bit hard to explain when you show a "C:\" path in your question, but imagine that said "K:\" - which is how you have the drive mapped, but another user might have it mapped to "V:\".  Or they may only have read-access while you have write-access.)  Check that they can manually save the workbook to the desired location.

Comment: Figured out the issue. The issue was some of the users had read and write while others had only read access. Sorted it out guys!. Thanks

Comment: @AnanthPatri In that case you may like to accept the suggested duplicate flag.  (I'm not sure what you, as the questioner, see on your screen but I believe there is a way for you to accept the suggestion and it will automatically close the question.)